# How to call an application controller method from angular js directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I want to make a validation directive. It basically will call a remote validation on the server. I would expect something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="nome" required ng-model="client.context" available="checkAvailableContexts">
```

and that should call a method on my ClientController like this:

```
$scope.checkAvailableContexts = function(contexto, callbacks) {
    service.checkContextAvailability(contexto, callbacks);
}
```

and this is my service method:

```
this.checkContextAvailability = function(context, externalCallbacks) {
 var url = angular.url("/clients/context/" + context + "/available"),
     callback = {
         success: function(){},
         error: function(){}
     };

 $.extend(callback, externalCallbacks)
 $.ajax({
     url: url,
     data: { context: context },
     success: function(data){
         $timeout(function(){
             callback.success(data); 
         },100);
     },
     type: "GET",
     dataType: "json",
     contentType: "application/json;charset=UTF-8onte"   
 });
};
```

my directive is something like this:

```
.directive('available', function(){
  return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      replace: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){
          controller.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                          //call the ClientsController method passing viewValue
                          //and callbacks that update the validity of the context
          })
      }
  }
})
```

But I can't figure out how to call the clientController from inside the directive.

I know I have attrs.available as the name of the function. But I can't execute it on the controller scope passing my parameters;

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call the control, you just need to share variables with it.

What you can do is share an object with the directive, like:

```
<input type="text" id="nome" 
 required ng-model="client.context" 
 available="availableOpts">
```

At your scope, you add a variable with shared vars, like:

```
$scope.availableOpts = {
   check: checkAvailableContexts,
   context: ...;
   callbacks: ...;
}
```

At you directive, you get it at the scope:

```
.directive('available', function(){
return {
  restrict: "A",
  require: "ngModel",
  replace: true,
  scope: {available: "="}
  link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller){

  // At this point, you have an variable at directive scope, that is shared
  // with the controller, so you can do:
  scope.available.check(scope.availabe.context, scope.available.callbacks);
  // the controler will have now a var $scope.availableOpts.result
  // with the return of the function tha you call

  }
 }
})
```