# Angularjs calling scope function in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to call a scope function from within a controller (which may or may not exist) from a directive.  Calling `fn()` by itself, doesn't work because the `fn()` may not exist.

I've used `scope.$apply('fn')` which works, however I need to pass in parameters into the function, such as `scope.$apply('fn(one, two)');` - this does not work.

Any suggestions how to call a function with parameters in a directive, that doesn't break if the controller has not yet defined the function?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the "may not exist" part, can you explain in a little more detail? The directive is used in multiple contexts and sometimes the enclosing controller has this function and sometimes not?

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598337/how-to-call-an-application-controller-method-from-angular-js-directive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call your function from a function like this :

```
scope.$apply(function(){
   fn(one, two);
});
```